# Is there any way to multiply array with string to the array with string in numpy?

Tags: python, string, list

My objective is to multiply variable with variable like derivation:
Example:

```
x = ['a', 'b']
y = ['c', 'd']
```

after multiply, it should look like this array:

```
z = ['a x c', 'b x d']
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with numpy. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways with `map`:

```
z = [*map('{} x {}'.format, x, y)]
z = [*map(' x '.join, zip(x, y))]
```

Answer (score 2):

### With numpy:

You could use `np.char.add`:

```
>>> np.char.add(np.char.add(x, ' x '), y)
array(['a x c', 'b x d'], dtype='<U5')
>>>
```

### Without numpy:

```
z = [' x '.join(i) for i in zip(x, y)]
```

Or:

```
z = [a + ' x ' + b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Or:

```
 z = [f'{a} x {b}' for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure python you could try this code:

```py
def mult(_: list, __: list):
    if not isinstance(_, list) or not isinstance(__, list) or not _.__len__() == __.__len__():
        raise TypeError('please provide lists of same length')
    return ['{} x {}'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(_, __)]
```

Example: (should work as is)

```py
>>> x = ['a', 'b']
>>> y = ['c', 'd']
>>> print(mult(x, y))
['a x c', 'b x d']
```

Comment: Perhaps for clarity (Zen), provide variable names and use `len()` rather than the dunder.

Comment: Wasn't just talking about the variables but also the `__len__`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more easier way:

```py
from sympy import *

init_printing(use_unicode=True)

K = Matrix([['a', 'b', 'c']])

L = Matrix(['g', 'h', 'i'])

print(K*L)
```

output:

```
Matrix([[a * g + b * h + c * i]])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).